# How Do You Sort Items By Set in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have this simple array with the following items:

```
[4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I want to sort it on this way:

```
[4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

As you notice, I want to sort it on descending order. But on this case, there are two sets of array that was sorted on descending order:

```
4, 3, 1, 0 and 1, 0
```

Which produce the output:

```
[4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I tried to do this using Group By:

```
var result = arrayInput.GroupBy(c => c).Select(a => a.OrderBy(d => d).First());
```

But this produces only `4, 3, 1, 0` and I need to append the not selected integers as sorted so that it will be:

```
[4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: That's not going to be a simple query.  Also how do you decide that it's [4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0] instead of [1, 0, 4, 3, 1, 0]?

Comment: You want sort different subset of collection in different way. So you should somehow divide collection, sort them and then combine back together. Main problem here is how to decide which item goes which subset

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to sort the numbers excluding duplicates, then list duplicates afterwards (also sorted)? What if there were 3 zeros, should all be shown?

Comment: @Fabio Yes. And yes, all will be shown. As long as they are sorted in descending order. If its 4, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 -> It will be sorted as 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Shouldn't that be 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0?  And if not why?  Because what you have is just a normal sort.

Comment: I just edited it. Sorry. By the way regarding your question, your answer is correct as well. Regardless of how it was composed as long as the sets are sorted properly that would be fine. @juharr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do that.  Basically you want to try putting each number into a group of sets.  The first one that doesn't already have that number is the one it actually goes in and if none have it then you add a new set.  In this way the first set will have all unique numbers, the second with have all numbers that are duplicated as least once, and so on.  Then at the end you return items for each of the sets ordering each set as you go.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SetSort(this IEnumerable<int> nums) {
    var sets = new List<HashSet<int>>();
    foreach(var num in nums) {
        bool added = false;
        foreach(var set in sets) {
            added = set.Add(num);
            if(added) break;
        }
        if(!added){
            sets.Add(new HashSet<int> { num });
        }
    }

    foreach(var set in sets) {
        foreach(var num in set.OrderByDescending(x => x)) {
            yield return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am having errors upon pasting your code on the declaration of sets variable = 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'.

Comment: @WillyDavidJr I was missing a `new` when creating the list.  I've fixed that.  Also I made it an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

As usually `Aggregate` extension method can do everything

```
var data = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
var result = 
    data.GroupBy(i => i)
        .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
        .Aggregate(new { Keys = new List<int>(), Duplicates = new List<int>() }, 
                   (lists, group) =>
                   {
                       lists.Keys.Add(group.Key);
                       var duplicates = Enumerable.Repeat(group.Key, group.Count() - 1);
                       lists.Duplicates.AddRange(duplicates);
                       return lists;
                   },
                   lists => lists.Keys.Concat(lists.Duplicates));

// result is new[] { 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
```

Approach with immutable collections

```
private IEnumerable<int> SortFunc(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    var ordered = 
        data.GroupBy(i => i)
            .OrderByDescending(group => group.Key)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                Key = group.Key,
                Duplicates = group.Skip(1)
            });

    foreach (var key in ordered.Select(group => group.Key))
    {
        yield return key;
    }

    foreach (var value in ordered.SelectMany(group => group.Duplicates))
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. A challenge for you: can you do it with *immutable* lists, in pure functional style?

Comment: This fails in the case when you have 3 0's, you'd end up with `[4,3,2,1,0,1,1,0,0]`. EDIT: you could fix this by recursively processing the duplicates list.

Comment: @CallbackKid, what is input in your case? If input has 3 `0`, then output contains three `0`: one in subset of distincts and rest two zeros are in subset of duplicates

Comment: I think OP would want to have the following: INPUT `[1,2,3,4,1,0,1,0,0]` -> OUTPUT `[4,3,2,1,0,1,0,1,0]` where the output contains 3 sorted lists `[4,3,2,1,0]`, `[1,0]`, and `[1,0]`

Comment: I could be wrong in assuming the correct output from OP. But now with your edit, it would be quite easy to achieve that result. Your second forloop line would become `for.... in SortFunc(ordered.SelectMany(g=>g.Duplicates)))`

Comment: @CallbackKid, Question and comments little bid confusing but based on accepted answer you a right

Comment: @EricLippert - there is my approach with "immutable" collections, is there are another possible solutions?

Comment: Nice solution! One small alternative solution would be to use `return ordered.Select(g=>g.Key).Concat(ordered.SelectMany(g=>g.Duplicates));` which is a little shorter but basically the same.